# What to use: Record or Cursor?

Tags: sql, oracle11g, cursor, record

Create a PL/SQL block to retrieve and display data for all pledges made in a specified month.  One row of output should be displayed for each pledge.  Include the following in each row of output:

•   Pledge ID, donor ID, and pledge amount
•   If the pledge is being paid in a lump sum, display “Lump Sum”.
•   If the pledge is being paid in a monthly payments, display “Monthly - #” (with the # representing the number of months for payment)
•   The list should be sorted to display all lump sum pledges first.

here is the table struc.

```
CREATE TABLE DD_Pledge (
                   idPledge number(5),
                   idDonor number(4),
                   Pledgedate DATE,
                   Pledgeamt number(8,2),
                   idProj number(5),
                   idStatus number(2),
                   Writeoff number(8,2),
                   paymonths number(3),
                   Campaign number(4),
                   Firstpledge char(1),
                   CONSTRAINT pledge_id_pk PRIMARY KEY(idPledge),
                   CONSTRAINT pledge_idDonor_fk FOREIGN KEY (idDonor)
                           REFERENCES dd_donor (idDonor), 
                   CONSTRAINT pledge_idProj_fk FOREIGN KEY (idProj)
                           REFERENCES dd_project (idProj),
                   CONSTRAINT pledge_idStatus_fk FOREIGN KEY (idStatus)
                           REFERENCES dd_status (idStatus));
```

I tried to use record but seems that record is not going to work as it gives me error when the specified month has more then one pledge. Is there a way to do it using record (coz this is and assignment we take it after we covered the record)

Maybe cursor will be a good choice but due to the point mentioned earlier I'd like to know what are the ways to solve this one.

Comment: Include a copy of the table definitions, ie what columns they contain, which are primary keys, which are foreign/related keys, what types they are, etc.  In short, sounds like what you're doing wouldn't need a cursor.  Nothing, ever, _needs_ a cursor.

Comment: @Sepster I edited the question sorry my bad I was doing the other question

Comment: So where in here do I find if it's a monthly or lump sum payment?  Regardless, surely eg the `case` statement in my answer gives you the clues you need to resolve this for a single table?

Comment: What do you mean by 'record' - are you getting an ORA-02112 error using `select ... into ...` when there's more than one row? That would be expected, and you'd need to use a cursor to iterate over the values. (Not that this needs a PL/SQL block, it can be done in SQL as @Sepster shows, but since it's an exercise...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT
  p.idPledge,
  p.idDonor,
  p.Pledgeamt as this_payment,
  case 
    when p.paymonths = 0 then 'Lump Sum'
    else 'Monthly - ' || p.paymonths 
  end as payment_method
FROM
  dd_pledge p
WHERE
  TRUNC(p.Pledgedate) >= '01-Mar-2010' AND TRUNC(p.Pledgedate) < '01-Apr-2010'  
order by
  4
```

Assuming you'll add your month's start/end dates as required.